urllib3/connectionpool.py line 1180 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
Anytime I run a conda command, the command crashes with this error repeated multiple times
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                      
  File "/home/spotparking/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/weakref.py", line 667, in _exitfunc
    f()
  File "/home/spotparking/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/weakref.py", line 591, in __call__
    return info.func(*info.args, **(info.kwargs or {}))
  File "/home/spotparking/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1180, in _close_pool_connections
    conn.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

I have tried uninstalling urllib3 and reinstalling it, and I have also tried conda update --all. The update command successfully updates all packages, but it similarly ends with this error being printed multiple times.
Any help in getting rid of this error message would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance
Here is the output from conda list
(spot) ../spotparking/SpotBackend$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/spotparking/miniconda3/envs/spot:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
absl-py                   2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
aiofiles                  24.1.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohappyeyeballs          2.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.10.5          py310h5b4e0ec_0    conda-forge
aiosignal                 1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
albucore                  0.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
albumentations            1.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
amazon-textract-caller    0.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
amazon-textract-response-parser 1.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
amazon-textract-textractor 1.7.11                   pypi_0    pypi
annotated-types           0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
async-timeout             4.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     23.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.1                    openblas    conda-forge
blinker                   1.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
boto3                     1.34.138                 pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.34.138                 pypi_0    pypi
bottleneck                1.4.0           py310hf462985_2    conda-forge
brotli                    1.1.0                hb9d3cd8_2    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.1.0                hb9d3cd8_2    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.1.0           py310hf71b8c6_2    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h4bc722e_7    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.8.30            hbcca054_0    conda-forge
cattrs                    23.2.3                   pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2024.6.2                 pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.17.1          py310h8deb56e_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.7           unix_pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
coremltools               7.2                      pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.8.5           py310hf71b8c6_1    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
docker-pycreds            0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
editdistance              0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
exceptiongroup            1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
executing                 2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
filelock                  3.15.4                   pypi_0    pypi
flask                     3.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
flatbuffers               24.3.25                  pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.53.0                   pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.12.1               h267a509_2    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.4.1           py310ha75aee5_1    conda-forge
fsspec                    2024.6.1                 pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gitdb                     4.0.11                   pypi_0    pypi
gitpython                 3.1.43                   pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.64.1                   pypi_0    pypi
h2                        4.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
hpack                     4.0.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
hyperframe                6.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.8                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
imageio                   2.34.2                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        8.4.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        8.4.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.29.5             pyh3099207_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.27.0             pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
itsdangerous              2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jeffutils                 0.9.8                    pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jmespath                  1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   h0b41bf4_3    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.2           py310hff52083_0    conda-forge
keras                     3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.21.3               h659f571_0    conda-forge
lazy-loader               0.4                      pypi_0    pypi
lcms2                     2.15                 hfd0df8a_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 hf3520f5_7    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           1_h86c2bf4_netlib    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.1.0                hb9d3cd8_2    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.1.0                hb9d3cd8_2    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.1.0                hb9d3cd8_2    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           6_ha36c22a_netlib    conda-forge
libclang                  18.1.1                   pypi_0    pypi
libdeflate                1.17                 h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_1  
libgcc                    14.1.0               h77fa898_1    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 14.1.0               h69a702a_1    conda-forge
libgfortran               14.1.0               h69a702a_1    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            14.1.0               h69a702a_1    conda-forge
libgfortran5              14.1.0               hc5f4f2c_1    conda-forge
libgomp                   14.1.0               h77fa898_1    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           6_ha36c22a_netlib    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.28          pthreads_h94d23a6_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.43               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.20               h4ab18f5_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.46.0               hde9e2c9_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx                 14.1.0               hc0a3c3a_1    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              14.1.0               h4852527_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.0                h6adf6a1_2    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.4.0                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libxcrypt                 4.4.36               hd590300_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h4ab18f5_6    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
markdown                  3.6                      pypi_0    pypi
markdown-it-py            3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.5           py310ha75aee5_1    conda-forge
marshmallow               3.21.3                   pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-base           3.9.2           py310hf02ac8c_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mdurl                     0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
ml-dtypes                 0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mpmath                    1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 6.0.5           py310ha75aee5_1    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
namex                     0.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.5                  he02047a_1    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
nomkl                     1.0                  h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.10.0          py310h3ea09b0_100    conda-forge
numpy                     1.26.4          py310heeff2f4_0  
numpy-base                1.26.4          py310h8a23956_0  
nvidia-cublas-cu12        12.1.3.1                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12    12.1.105                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12    12.1.105                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12  12.1.105                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cudnn-cu12         8.9.2.26                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cufft-cu12         11.0.2.54                pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-curand-cu12        10.3.2.106               pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cusolver-cu12      11.4.5.107               pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cusparse-cu12      12.1.0.106               pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-nccl-cu12          2.19.3                   pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12     12.5.82                  pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-nvtx-cu12          12.1.105                 pypi_0    pypi
objprint                  0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
onnx                      1.16.1                   pypi_0    pypi
openblas                  0.3.28          pthreads_hbcdf1e8_0    conda-forge
opencv-python             4.9.0.80                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python-headless    4.9.0.80                 pypi_0    pypi
openjpeg                  2.5.0                hfec8fc6_2    conda-forge
openssl                   3.3.2                hb9d3cd8_0    conda-forge
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
optree                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 24.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pafy                      0.5.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       24.2               pyh8b19718_1    conda-forge
platformdirs              4.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.47             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.20.3                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    6.0.0           py310hc51659f_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyaml                     24.4.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pycocotools               2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.22               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydantic                  2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pydantic-core             2.20.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pympler                   1.1                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.10.14         hd12c33a_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0              pypi_0    pypi
python-dotenv             1.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2024.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    5_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2024.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     26.2.0          py310h71f11fc_2    conda-forge
qhull                     2020.2               h434a139_5    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.32.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rich                      13.7.1                   pypi_0    pypi
s3transfer                0.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-image              0.24.0                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.13.2               hd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
seaborn-base              0.13.2             pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
sentry-sdk                2.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
setproctitle              1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                73.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
shapely                   2.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
smmap                     5.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.46.0               h6d4b2fc_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.14.2          py310h261611a_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tabulate                  0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.16.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.16.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.37.1                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
thop                      0.1.1-2209072238          pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tifffile                  2024.7.2                 pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.14               h39e8969_0  
torch                     2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.4.1           py310ha75aee5_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.66.1                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.14.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
triton                    2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.12.2               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.12.2             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2024a                h8827d51_1    conda-forge
unicodedata2              15.1.0          py310h2372a71_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
wandb                     0.17.1                   pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  3.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.44.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
xlsxwriter                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.4.6                h5eee18b_1  
yarl                      1.9.11          py310ha75aee5_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.5                ha4adb4c_5    conda-forge
zipp                      3.20.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h4ab18f5_6    conda-forge
zstandard                 0.23.0          py310ha39cb0e_1    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.6                ha6fb4c9_0    conda-forge

And here is the output from conda info:
(spot) ../spotparking/SpotBackend$ conda info

     active environment : spot
    active env location : /home/spotparking/miniconda3/envs/spot
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/spotparking/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/spotparking/.condarc
          conda version : 24.5.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.14.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
                          __conda=24.5.0=0
                          __cuda=12.3=0
                          __glibc=2.35=0
                          __linux=5.15.153.1=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /home/spotparking/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/spotparking/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/spotparking/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/spotparking/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/spotparking/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/spotparking/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/24.5.0 requests/2.32.2 CPython/3.10.14 Linux/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 ubuntu/22.04.3 glibc/2.35 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/24.1.0 libmambapy/1.5.8 aau/0.4.4 c/. s/. e/.
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

I am running all of these commands in Ubuntu WSL.
Edit:
Here is the output of conda list in my conda (base) environment:
(base) ../home/~$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/spotparking/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
anaconda-anon-usage       0.4.4           py310hfc0e8ea_100  
archspec                  0.2.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
boltons                   23.0.0          py310h06a4308_0  
brotli-python             1.0.9           py310h6a678d5_8  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h5eee18b_6  
c-ares                    1.19.1               h5eee18b_0  
ca-certificates           2024.8.30            hbcca054_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2024.8.30          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.16.0          py310h5eee18b_1  
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
comm                      0.2.1           py310h06a4308_0  
conda                     24.9.1          py310hff52083_0    conda-forge
conda-content-trust       0.2.0           py310h06a4308_1  
conda-libmamba-solver     24.1.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
conda-package-handling    2.3.0           py310h06a4308_0  
conda-package-streaming   0.10.0          py310h06a4308_0  
cryptography              42.0.5          py310hdda0065_1  
debugpy                   1.6.7           py310h6a678d5_0  
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
distro                    1.9.0           py310h06a4308_0  
exceptiongroup            1.2.0           py310h06a4308_0  
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
expat                     2.6.2                h6a678d5_0  
fmt                       9.1.0                hdb19cb5_1  
frozendict                2.4.2           py310h5eee18b_0  
icu                       73.1                 h6a678d5_0  
idna                      3.7             py310h06a4308_0  
ipykernel                 6.28.0          py310h06a4308_0  
ipython                   8.25.0          py310h06a4308_0  
jedi                      0.18.1          py310h06a4308_1  
jsonpatch                 1.33            py310h06a4308_1  
jsonpointer               2.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py310h06a4308_0  
jupyter_core              5.7.2           py310h06a4308_0  
krb5                      1.20.1               h143b758_1  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
libarchive                3.6.2                h6ac8c49_3  
libcurl                   8.7.1                h251f7ec_0  
libedit                   3.1.20230828         h5eee18b_0  
libev                     4.33                 h7f8727e_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_1  
libgcc                    14.1.0               h77fa898_1    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 14.1.0               h69a702a_1    conda-forge
libgomp                   14.1.0               h77fa898_1    conda-forge
libmamba                  1.5.8                hfe524e5_2  
libmambapy                1.5.8           py310h2dafd23_2  
libnghttp2                1.57.0               h2d74bed_0  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0  
libsolv                   0.7.24               he621ea3_1  
libssh2                   1.11.0               h251f7ec_0  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libuuid                   1.41.5               h5eee18b_0  
libxml2                   2.10.4               hfdd30dd_2  
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h6a678d5_1  
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py310h06a4308_0  
menuinst                  2.1.1           py310h06a4308_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
nest-asyncio              1.6.0           py310h06a4308_0  
openssl                   3.3.2                hb9d3cd8_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2            py310h06a4308_0  
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pcre2                     10.42                hebb0a14_1  
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3  
pip                       24.0            py310h06a4308_0  
platformdirs              3.10.0          py310h06a4308_0  
pluggy                    1.0.0           py310h06a4308_1  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43          py310h06a4308_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0  
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h5eee18b_0  
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pybind11-abi              4                    hd3eb1b0_1  
pycosat                   0.6.6           py310h5eee18b_1  
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pygments                  2.15.1          py310h06a4308_1  
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310h06a4308_0  
python                    3.10.14              h955ad1f_1  
python-dateutil           2.9.0post0      py310h06a4308_2  
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py310h6a678d5_0  
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
reproc                    14.2.4               h6a678d5_2  
reproc-cpp                14.2.4               h6a678d5_2  
requests                  2.32.2          py310h06a4308_0  
ruamel.yaml               0.17.21         py310h5eee18b_0  
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.6           py310h5eee18b_1  
setuptools                69.5.1          py310h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
sqlite                    3.45.3               h5eee18b_0  
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
tk                        8.6.14               h39e8969_0  
tornado                   6.4.1           py310h5eee18b_0  
tqdm                      4.66.4          py310h2f386ee_0  
traitlets                 5.14.3          py310h06a4308_0  
truststore                0.8.0           py310h06a4308_0  
typing_extensions         4.11.0          py310h06a4308_0  
tzdata                    2024a                h04d1e81_0  
urllib3                   2.2.2           py310h06a4308_0  
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
wheel                     0.43.0          py310h06a4308_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h5eee18b_1  
yaml-cpp                  0.8.0                h6a678d5_1  
zeromq                    4.3.5                h6a678d5_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_1  
zstandard                 0.22.0          py310h2c38b39_0  
zstd                      1.5.5                hc292b87_2 


Please show the conda list output for your base env

@FlyingTeller I updated the question to include conda list from the base environment
